# How do I update a record in a MySql database with multiple records connected in other tables?

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, sql-update

I have an interesting problem here.  I have a MySql database table that has is linked to several other tables.  For example, the "main" table is a set of teaching materials, along with connected tables:

- Grades that the material is aimed at;
- Grammar points that the material is best used for;
- Keywords associated with the material

I want to be able to update and change these records.  Changing the main record is easy enough, but what about the connected records? For example, let's say that I have a teaching material that I originally intend to teach verbs and adjectives, and is best used for grades 1-4. Now later on, I decide to add grade 5 to the list, remove grade 1, and that the material is actually better for teaching nouns and adjectives, but not verbs.

What would be the best way to update the grade and grammar tables? I don't want to inadvertently overwrite data that I wanted to keep, nor to keep data that I wanted deleted.  Should I just wipe out all the records associated with that particular teaching material and re-enter them, or is there some other way that I can index them so that they can be more efficiently updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can link your tables by foreign keys. That is, you have your connected records which share these keys. Then, depending on how you instantiate your tables, you can use a `CASCADE` when you update a value in one table. From [the manual on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), when you define this foreign key you can set the `CASCADE` as follows:

> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
> [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
> [ON DELETE reference_option]
> [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
> RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
> ```

Where:

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

By default, this reference option is set to `No Action`.

Comment: Don't forget that foreign keys works only with the InnoDB engine.

Comment: @biz really? Ive only used oracle so i didn't know it wasn't universal, but isn't mySQL oracle anyway?

Comment: No, the `MyISAM` engine is much dumber, it is absolutely not ACID compliant, no foreign keys, no transactions.

Comment: The problem here is this: let's go back to the example I put in my question.  The user goes to the edit page, adds a grade, deletes another one, and does the same with grammar points.  What sql queries can I run to accomplish this without either overwriting data that I want to keep or leaving orphaned data that I no longer want?  A simple update won't work because I'm adding one thing, removing another, and leaving everything else as-is. Should I just delete all records associated with the parent record and re-enter them, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: That said, your answer taught me something new, which will definitely be of help to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have two tables one called Vendor and the other called Inventory

```
++++++++++++++

 +Vendor

++++++++++++++

 +Vendor_ID 
 +Vendor_Name

 ++++++++++++++ 

 +++++++++++++++

 +Inventory

 +++++++++++++++

 +Description

 +endor_Name

 +Price

 +Weight

 +++++++++++++++
```

Currently the Vendor_Name in both tables has the same value so I can do

```
SELECT Vendor.Vendor_ID 
 FROM Vendor, Inventory 
 WHERE Vendor.Vendor_Name = Inventory.Vendor_Name
```